# WooCommerce subscription status get issue

Tags: php, woocommerce, subscription, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using a function in `function.php` of theme:

I am checking that at login, if user has not active subscription than it should redirect to a page. I have two users, one has active subscription and other has expired. But when I use this code for both users, both are going in the else condition, which means no subscription.

It's not a product subscription, it's a subscription for user's plans.

```
$active_subscriptions = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => $user_id,
    'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription', // Subscription post type
    'post_status' => 'wc-active', // Active subscription
));

if (!empty($active_subscriptions)) {
    echo "1";
    die;
    return true;
} else {
    echo "2";
    die;
}
```

Comment: No one is expert here?

Comment: why do you need to use "die"?

Comment: @HussainMahfoodh i am just checking which condition its coming... 
do you have any proper solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the `wcs_get_subscriptions` function.

```
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions(
    array(
        'customer_id' => $user_id,
        'subscription_status' => 'wc-active',
        'subscriptions_per_page' => - 1
    )
);
```

Comment: This is showing shop_subscription, i need subscription for the users who is done at time of account creation, actually when a user signup the site, he has to select one package and have to pay... so we have to check that subscription of user at signup.. so can you please help me out for that

Comment: i want to see membership plan subscription.. so please help me out on this @Van

Comment: First you need to track somehow which subscription the user created account with. If they are able to later signup for something else or they cancel the first and add another subscription, you will need to be able to get the first one. You can probably save the subscription id to the user meta, if you need to track the first user subscription.

The function above will give you all active subscriptions for the passed user, so it should give you this signup subscription.